# Printing command leads to crash

Tags: windows-xp, printer, network-printer

Every time I try and print a document the software I use crashes for some reason. I'm running Windows XP 64-bit Professional. I have a HP network printer and other computers can print fine, it's just mine that won't.

Comment: Which printer is it? How exactly do you connect to the printer? Over a print server or directly? Have you tried removing the printer and reinstalling drivers? Please [edit] and give us some more information.

Comment: Also what software are you printing from? Is it just one piece of software that this problem occurs from or from all programs?

Comment: this happens from every single piece of software. The printer is connected to the network switch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you print from any other program? If the answer is yes, you have isolated the error to this program - see if any upgrades are available.

If you can't print from any application, or if you have tried upgrading the program to the latest version already, I would recommend you look for a print driver upgrade just in case it is a compatibility issue.

Comment: No, every single program crashes when I try to print from it. Okay thank you, I will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

If your HP driver is PCL6, Try removing the printer and reinstalling using a PCL5e driver.